# "TypeError : Cannot read property 'address' of undefined" i receive this error after lunch the deploy in the testnet, but in localhost works

Tags: javascript, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

i receive this error `TypeError : Cannot read property 'address' of undefined` after lunched `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`, but the same command in localhost works well, why?

**hardhat.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.4',
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    goerli: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    }
  },
};
```

**deploy.js**

the error seems to be here, but i don't get why lunching npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js works well and with goerly (or other testnet not)

**if i write  `console.log(accounts[0].address); console.log(accounts[1].address)`; , i get the log only of the first one!**

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const main = async () => {
  let accounts;
  accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
  const OWNERS = [
    accounts[0].address,
    accounts[1].address,
    accounts[2].address
  ]
  const NUM_CONFIRMATIONS = 2

  const MultiSig = await ethers.getContractFactory("MultiSig");
  const multiInstance = await MultiSig.deploy(OWNERS, NUM_CONFIRMATIONS);

  const TestContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("TestContract");
  const testContract = await TestContract.deploy("msg");

  await multiInstance.deployed();
  await testContract.deployed();

  console.log('multisig contract address: ', multiInstance.address);
  console.log('test contract address: ', testContract.address);
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

runMain();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe i got it, i added only 1 private key, i have to add more in the "accounts"array